# Xcode 6: what does "Add to new server" item in "source control: create git repository in ..." pulldown mean?

Tags: xcode, git, github, xcode6

I wish to create a new Xcode project that will be mirrored on GitHub.

So I select OS X commandline project.

Now a dialog appears for me to choose a target folder.

At the bottom is this:

[image]

Now every tutorial I seen says to choose "My Mac", then create a new repo on my account on github.com, and then link the two together using the commandline.  Something like `git remote add https://github.com/me/fooproj`.

What is this second option? Does it somehow bypass the need for using the commandline to link? i.e. Can I just use it and put the github repo url in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't just input the github repo url. This option refers to connecting to a Mac OS X Server running the Xcode service. For more information, check the link below:

http://help.apple.com/serverapp/mac/4.0/#/apdEC37D10C-B277-4C06-9E1F-8DCB0A5970EB